# Update depending on a column's value with Esqueleto

Tags: haskell, esqueleto

I want to update a table `t` having column `c1` and `c2` by a Haskell function of type `fx :: c1 -> c2` now I want to apply this function to my table `t` and update the values of `c2`. How I can do this in one run? Like in postgres I will write it as:
`update t set c2 = fx(c1);`
What will be the esqueleto equivalent for the same ?

Comment: I have very little experience with esqueleto, but I don't think you can do this in "one run" as you want. For that, the Haskell function should have to be computed by the SQL server, and I would be very surprised if you could "export" arbitrary functions to SQL. This could be possible for specific `fx`, though. (Maybe esqueleto allows one to write some functions using special restricted syntax that in the end can be translated into SQL code? I have no idea.)